# How can we use search conditions (.. and ..or..) for columns instead of rows in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, entity-attribute-value

Im working on a php-mysql real estate project and its nearly done. But im in trouble with "detailed property search" part. I do not know if I could express my question sufficiently title, but im gonna explain you all.

In the critical part, i have 3 tables in my project: "properties","property_details", and "features". The properties table stores the fundemantal informations about each properties like id,title,category,sub category,city ext. The features table stores the all possible spesific features for properties. And it has 3 columns: id,title and value. The title column refers to another table, so it is irrelevant for this question. And lastly, the property_details table has 3 columns: property_id,feature_id, and value. You can ask me "why you use value column twice in two tables?" but some features has fixed values (like has garage or not) and some features values are typing by user like number of rooms.

In "detailed property search" page, the program lists all proper features for selected property category and by the user's choises, it creates a long sql where condition like : "(property_details.feature_id = 4 and property_details.value < 10) Or (...) And (...) ext. My problem starts here, i know mysql runs queries row by row, but in my property_details table, a property can be more than one and have too many different features. But i cant use my where condition because of different rows. Is there any way to do queries with my spesific "where" contidions by columns instead of rows? Or any other advices? I would be grateful for your help!

I want to show you what i need exactly:
property_details table:

### property_id| feature_id | value

```
 1     |     3      |  10
 1     |     4      |  11
 2     |     3      |  9
 1     |     2      | 200
```

My table is looks like that now. And i need to find a property which (feature_id = 3 AND feature_id = 4) Or (feature_id = 2 AND value > 100). I cant make this query naturally. But i need to do. Because there are lots of different features (about 400-500) and making every feature as a column is not logical. I need to use this table as such.

Comment: All where conditions are column based

Comment: Yes, but it works only the columns which at the same row. I need to use my condition for same column in different rows at the same time.

Comment: That is where the value of the column comes in.

Comment: Hi Jay. I update my question to be more clear. Sorry for my english. But please look at my table example. The property, which id is 1, has 3 different features. And i need to find it with my where condition. The property 1 is in 3 different rows and has 3 different values. And may be other properties can lay down the same conditions, i need to find all of them to show as a result

Comment: Are you using joins ? Because this looks like a typical join Solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `EXISTS` here:

```
SELECT * FROM   properties prp
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM property_details pd
    WHERE  pd.property_id = prp.id
    AND    pd.feature_id = 3
)
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM property_details pd
    WHERE  pd.property_id = prp.id
    AND    pd.feature_id = 4
)
OR EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM property_details pd
    WHERE  pd.property_id = prp.id
    AND    pd.feature_id = 2
    AND    pd.value > 100
)
```

It's not elegant, but that's the consequence of using an EAV model. I know by experience that sometimes EAV is inevitable, so I won't urge you not to use it, but it won't ever be convenient in querying and presenting.

Comment: Thanks Gert. But what can descend deeper? I mean, i will never know how many ands - ors i have to use on my query, the users will choose the features and program will creates the condition automatically. If i have to add EXISTS{} blocks for each "and" and "or" (which amounts unpredictible numbers) it looks impossible to code. I think i'm missing something which is evident. How can i adapt this to an infinity numbers of conditions?

Comment: Impossible to code? On the contrary. The idea is that each predicate simply adds one `EXISTS`. I use the same pattern in production code. You should try if performance becomes a problem when there are "many" predicates. Make sure that there is a combined index on `property_id` and `feature_id`.

Comment: I got the point bro. Thank you so much! Wish there were a simple query to do that but anyway i can do my conditions now. Now i have to look for performance optimizations :)

Answer (score 1):

For OR-condditions:

```
select distinct property_id
from property_details
where feature_id = 3 and value = 4
   or feature_id = 2 and value > 100
```

For AND-conditions:

```
select property_id
from property_details pd
where feature_id = 3 and value = 4
   or feature_id = 2 and value > 100
group by property_id
having count(*) = 2
```

Or using a join:

```
select d1.property_id
from property_details d1
join property_details d2 using (property_id)
where d1.feature_id = 3 and d1.value = 4
  and d2.feature_id = 1 and d2.value > 100
```

Search for "Entity-Attribute-Value-Model" to find more problems and solutions related to this design.

Comment: Thanks for great solution Paul. Every part of this solution is good for me, but how can i add unpredictable numbers of conditions to this queries? I mean, the user can selects random pice of features like 2+1,on 6th floor, with garden, swimming pool ext.. My program creates automatically long and long conditions mixed with "ands" and "ors". I can seperete them like only "ands" and "ors" but for example it creates a condition which have 15 ands and 20 ors (total 35), should i join the same table for 35 times? I nearly gonna cry :) You seem to have the key that will save me, think that please